# Mod rewrite, remove directory and keep URL variable

Tags: .htaccess, url, variables, mod-rewrite, directory

How can i replace this,

http://test.com/c/news/?s=hello

Into this?
http://test.com/c/?page=news&s=hello

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/c/news/.*$ /c/?page=news [QSA,L]
```

QSA Means Query String Append and appends the query string from the original url to the new url